# jQuery callback function how to

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have the following code and I am confused on what's going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showCurrentPosition(position){
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            alert(latitude);
        });


    }
    else{
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
    }
});
```

I am unable to execute alert in showCurrentPosition function. How to do such things in jQuery?

Comment: **First point -** what is the question?? **Second Point-** Why that extra `});` at the end??

Comment: There isn't extra }); at the end...

Comment: code is working fine

Comment: Please ask clearly what you need

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {});` is the only part of this that would make sense with jQuery, and it looks like you are already there :)

Comment: How far does it get? If you set a break point, what is the last line that is hit? Any errors in the console?

Comment: no error. it goes till - if(navigator.geolocation){..}

Answer (score 2):

Your callback function be

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () {
         showCurrentPosition(position);
 });

 function showCurrentPosition(position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            alert(latitude);
 }
```